# Получение информации из открывшегося balloon в Яндекс картах

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

есть сервис по доставке еды. Заказчик пришел с правками по верстке, а в итоге перешли уже на правки функционала, попросил сделать расчет стоимости доставки, в зависимости от зоны.
Воспользовался сервисом яндекса "Проверка адреса на попадание в зону доставки", благо пример есть, по нему сделал. Тут все заработало, плюс balloon открывается на карте при вводе адреса. А вот как брать из него информацию (в моему случае там присутствует стоимость доставки) так я и не могу разобраться.
В поддержке яндекса скинули ссылку на getBalloonContent, но так как с js и jquery если сложности, я так и не смог понять как правильно воспользоваться полученной информацией.

Допустим я создаю переменную ballonContent. А как мне в нее определить данные из открытого на карте ballon?

`var ballonContent = getBalloonContent();`

Answer (score 0):

В случае с [примером](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/delivery_zones/) из песочницы Яндекса следует просто добавить в код отслеживание кликов на геообъектах:

```
myMap.geoObjects.events.add('click', function (e) {
    var targ = e.get('target')
    var balCont = targ.properties.get('balloonContent')
    console.log(balCont)    // вывод результата в консоль
});
```